# Excel macro: find last row, add todays date, autofilter, autosave

Tags: excel, vba

i have 4 questions regarding some excel macros im currently writing for my job.

**1.** i need a formula to find the last row of the file so i dont have to manually paste it every time i run it. i currently have:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K2:K148")
Range("K2:K148").Select
```

where i have to manually enter K148 every time. and its not only for that column.
so i would like a formula that saves the number of the last row and that i can just paste into it. like "ROWS=actualnumberofrows" so that the one im using would look like this:

every time i run it. i currently have:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K2:K(ROWS)")
Range("K2:K(ROWS)").Select
```

.2. when i want to paste a date into my excel form because my program needs it, it pastes it in the wrong format. heres my formula:

```
Range("N2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Date
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N148"), Type:=xlFillCopy
Range("N2:N148").Select
```

but it pastes it as year/month/date and i need it as year-month-date
how do i change it so that it automaticly does so?

.3. i dont have a function for this, but id like for an autofilter function to happen after this:

```
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
```

when i try to record the autofiltering in excel it filters by how many rows the one i recorded in has. this pretty much ties into question #1.

.4. i currently use this function for saving, but i have a problem with it:

```
Private Sub spara()


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "T:\Sweden\Routine leads\Adlantic+Euroads\MCM_" + ActiveWorkbook.Name _
    , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

it automaticly saves with , but i need it to save with ; in its file. is this possible to change how it saves somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code for your first question:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range("K2:K" & N)
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=r
    r.Select
End Sub
```